# Newly published extensions intallation crx_version_number_invalid

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I meet some problems about newly published extensions in this month.
    When I download my extensions from Developer Dashboard by this type
[image: public key]

I can install extension normally by pushing it into chrome, but now newly published extension cannot install it before version 60 and publish an error:

[image: CRX_VERSION_NUMBER_INVALID]

I don't know how to figure it or if web store did some crx package change?
Can anyone meet this problem?And help me.Tks.

PS: I download crx by other types from Google, this crx file can install normally and MD5 is different from crx file from  Developer Dashboard.

Comment: Based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476358/chrome-error-package-is-invalid-crx-version-number-invalid), it seems that Google update the crx file format recently. You can try to update the chrome to fix this issue or you can install the extension from the store.

Comment: where can i find the news the google posted,without update chrome how can i fix it @abielita

Answer (score 0):

- Try 1:- change Change ext version in manifist.Json
- Try 2:- remove really unwanted config from manifist.Json
- Try 3:- remove unwanted
  file from directory.